# Highcharts: bar/column chart label position with values of 0

Tags: highcharts

If I have a Highcharts bar or column chart that has a data series with an array of all zeroes, the y axis tick label displays in the center of the y axis, along with an extra y axis.  I've experimented with the tick placement and min values but these dont seem to work in the case of this peculiar set of data.  see http://jsfiddle.net/davidpmcintyre/mepd17tn/

Here's the highcharts code snippet:

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr' ]
        },      

        series: [{
            data: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        }]
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean "extra y-axis"? Do you mean the gridline? Also, how would you like it to look in that specific case?

Comment: I suppose that it's not actually a y-axis but instead a y-axis gridline.  But since the problem remains even after setting the y-axis's min to 0, it looks as if hte problem is the poorly-aligned y axis.  I expect the lone gridline to be positioned exactly where it would be if any of the values exceeded 0;  the y gridline/axis should be at the far left of the plot area.

Comment: Right. Well, there is no data to display as bars, so how do you ideally want it to look?

Comment: The gridline and label for 0 should be on the far left of the plot area, imo.

Comment: How about `min: 0, max: 1`?

Comment: Setting the max solves this particular problem, but I am hoping for a better solution because I would have to set the max after checking that the data is all zeroes. If i can't solve this problem the way i want by configuring the HC settings, can I fix it with css?

Comment: Can you assume that your y-axis will have a minimum value of 0 (no negative values)? And also, that it is okay to always start from 0?

Comment: yes, there will never be negative values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming (given requirements of your chart):

- All data will be positive
- You always want to start from 0 on the y-axis

The following code will allow you to left-align your y-axis, and also specify how much of the y-axis you want to show in minimal cases ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mepd17tn/1/)):

```
yAxis: {
    min: 0,
    minRange: 1
}
```

This will still allow you to have larger ranges on the y-axis as it only kicks in when the value range is less than one. This in turn means you do not have to check your data before setting any values.